# Find and manipulate array element in KSH

Tags: ksh, array

I have an array that reads like this:

```
# echo "${ARRAY[@]}"
1=Napp Slice
4=NNN Issue
3=GG Allow
2=CO-OP
1=Quit
```

And I want to loop through it to see if any contain the word `Quit` and if so, set that element to a variable. So I ran below:

```bsh
for x in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
  if [ $x == *Quit* ]; then
    FOO=$x
    echo $FOO
  else
    break
  fi
done
```

I want returned to me `1=Quit`
but when I run it I get:

```
# ./myScript.ksh
1=Napp Slice
4=NNN Issue
3=GG Allow
2=CO-OP
1=Quit
```

How can I pull out *just* the element containing `Quit`?

I really tried to see if this question existed before posting, I am newer to shell-scripting. I am sure there is something very simple that I am missing but I can't seem to get it.

KSH syntax only please as that is all I have available to me.

## EDIT: I still need to figure out how to delete the element once found

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting errors when I try to run your script with `ksh93`, mainly because `==` does not work within `[ ... ]`.  It is unclear to me what shell you're using. You are also executing `break` as soon as you don't match the pattern, which means you probably only ever run one iteration of your loop. It's unclear what outputs your array, but it is most likely not the code you show.

In any case, the following script does what you want in the `ksh93` shell (and in `bash` as it turns out, and `zsh`):

```bsh
array=(
        '1=Napp Slice'
        '4=NNN Issue'
        '3=GG Allow'
        '2=CO-OP'
        '1=Quit'
)

for element in "${array[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$element" == *Quit* ]]; then
                foo=$element
                printf '%s\n' "$foo"
                break
        fi
done
```

Note the use of `[[ ... ]]` with the pattern matching operator `==`. Also, be careful to quote the expansion of `${array[@]}` so that you get each element individually quoted and not split on spaces.

In the comments, you say you want to delete the element from the array.  You can't do that if you loop over the elements of the array, but you may unset the element if you instead iterate over the array's indexes.

```bsh
for index in "${!array[@]}"; do
        if [[ "${array[index]}" == *Quit* ]]; then
                foo=${array[index]}
                unset -v 'array[index]'
                printf '%s\n' "$foo"
                break
        fi
done
```

Note that this potentially gives you an array with a "missing" element somewhere and that numeric indexes no longer are consecutive.

---

The code below reproduces approximately what the second code block above does, but for `sh`, with some extra functionality added.  It is provided here purely for our own amusement.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set --  '1=Napp Slice'  \
        '4=NNN Issue'   \
        '3=GG Allow'    \
        '2=CO-OP'       \
        '1=Quit'

unset -v found

for element do
        shift
        case $element in (*Quit*) found=$element; continue; esac
        set -- "$@" "$element"
done

printf 'Element = %s\n' "${found-(was not found)}"
printf 'Remaining list:\n'
printf '\t%s\n' "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you @they! That did it :) Sorry for the lack of info, yes I am using ksh93 and it works like a charm

Comment: how would I then remove that element from the array? When I try to do it within the loop, I get error: "1=Quit: is not an identifier"

Comment: @ShelbyAnne See updated answer.